# What do the symbols *1 or &2 mean in Travis CI deployment scripts?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm following the guide for using Travis to [deploy to AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/codedeploy/). In those docs they point to a [`.travis.yml` example](https://github.com/travis-ci/cat-party/blob/master/.travis.yml) which contains the following code:

```
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: AKIAJ4XZHIMNKP3WGGHQ
    secret_access_key: &1
      secure: <key>
    local_dir: dpl_cd_upload
    skip_cleanup: true
    on: &2
      repo: travis-ci/cat-party
    bucket: catparty-codedeploy
  - provider: codedeploy
    access_key_id: AKIAJ4XZHIMNKP3WGGHQ
    secret_access_key: *1
    bucket: catparty-codedeploy
    key: latest.zip
    bundle_type: zip
    application: CatPartyDemoApplication
    deployment_group: ProductionDemoFleet
    on: *2
```

I've got this working and understand the flow (first it uploads the zip file to S3, then it deploys that file to CodeDeploy). What I'm struggling with is the syntax: specifically the `on: &2` line in the `s3` section, and the `on: *2` part in the `codedeploy` section. What are these lines doing?

I ask because I want to modify this configuration to deploy to a different CodeDeploy group depending on whether the commit has a given tag, eg:

```
on:
  tags: true
  all_branches: true
  condition: "$TRAVIS_TAG =~ ^release.*$"
```

... but because I'm not clear what the `on: *2` is doing (and can't find it in the docs), I'm uncertain how to proceed. Any tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those symbols and the features they bring are part of YAML itself. They're supported to reduce duplication efforts in a YAMl file.

For instance, this section prefixed with the `&` stores the subsequent structure as a reference with the name `2`. So `2` now references `repo: travis-ci/cat-party`.

`on: &2
  repo: travis-ci/cat-party`

The reference name can also be a an alphanumeric set of characters to make things more expressive.

On the other hand, `*` is then used to resolve that reference where you want to reuse it.

So in the following section the YAML parser would resolve the `*2` to the structure previously stored: `repo: travis-ci/cat-party`:

`on: *2`

This feature saves you duplication, which can be handy in several aspects of a `.travis.yml` file.